# Call a database variable with SQL in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a database with the tables `program` and `class`. The `class` table has a foreign key from `program`, the `id_program`. In the PHP code below, I fetch the data from the `class` table and works great.

```
<?php
    $A_apotelesma = NULL;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM class";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('Error, query failed');
    $i=-1;

    if ($result) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $i++;
            $A_apotelesma[$i]['id_program'] = $row['id_program'];
            $A_apotelesma[$i]['id_class'] = $row['id_class'];
            $A_apotelesma[$i]['onoma'] = $row['onoma'];
            $A_apotelesma[$i]['imera'] = $row['imera'];
            $A_apotelesma[$i]['time_start'] = $row['time_start'];
            $A_apotelesma[$i]['time_end'] = $row['time_end'];
        }
    }

    echo "<table border=\"1\" bordercolor=\"#ff8533\">";

    if(is_array($A_apotelesma)){
        echo "  <tr>
                    <td colspan='7' align='center'><strong><br>Στοιχεία υπάρχοντων τμημάτων:</strong><br><br></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align='left'>ID</td>
                    <td align='left'>Πρόγραμμα</td>
                    <td align='left'>Όνομα</td> 
                    <td align='left'>Ημέρα</td>
                    <td align='left'>Ώρα έναρξης</td>
                    <td align='left'>Ώρα λήξης</td>
                </tr>";
        foreach($A_apotelesma as $in => $value){

            echo "<tr>
                <th width='16%'>".$value['id_class']."</th>
                <th width='16%'>".$value['id_program']."</th>
                <th width='16%'>".$value['onoma']."</th>
                <th width='16%'>".$value['imera']."</th>
                <th width='16%'>".$value['time_start']."</th>
                <th width='16%'>".$value['time_end']."</th> 
                    <td>                            
                    Διαγραφή τμήματος<br>
                    <img src=\"images/del.jpg\" onclick='delete_class(".$value['id_class'].")' onmouseover=\"this.style.cursor='pointer'\" />                                                                           
                </td>                               
            </tr>";
        }
    }
    else
        echo "<tr><th>Δεν βρέθηκαν τμήματα.</th></tr>";
        echo "</table>";
?>
```

I just would like in the `foreach` command the `".$value['id_program']."` not to be the `id_program` value, but another value, called `onoma` from the "program" table. I tried:

```
SELECT onoma FROM program LEFT JOIN class ON program.id_program=class.id_program
```

but no luck. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The JOIN is the anwer, but use inner join https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. You cannot overwite the id_program, you have to call it something else in the select statement

```
SELECT Program.Onoma as Onoma
FROM Program
INNER JOIN Class
ON Class.id_program = Program.id;
```

Comment: I did this:
      $res = "SELECT program.onoma as onoma FROM program INNER JOIN class ON class.id_program=program.id_program";

and then instead of 
.$value['id_program']." 
I replaced with
".$res."

I don't get any errors, but no results. It just prints the SQL line in the cell

Comment: Did you actually use a query? $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('Error, query failed'); and then $query = the select statement?

Comment: Yes, I actually did. There's something else I'm doing wrong. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Need to join two tables rather than selecting values from single table.Replace your `query`:

```
$query = "SELECT c.id_class,c.imera,c.time_start,c.time_end,p.program_name,p.onoma FROM class c  INNER JOIN program p ON c.id_program=p.id_program";
```

**See** `program_name` name is used instead of `program_id` to display program name from `program` table.